# Use of IGNORE_DUP_KEY in Oracle database (sqlplus)

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to run the following code on less than 10000 rows, but I'm getting

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (constraint_name) violated (not unexpected).

```
UPDATE table1
   SET EMAILADRESSE = replace(EMAILADRESSE,'@domain1.no','@domain2.no')
 WHERE EMAILADRESSE LIKE '%@domain1.no' ;
```

Tried `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`, but this is not supported in oracle/SQL*PLUS as far as my research shows. Do you have any alternatives for me?

Comment: There is no such hint as `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` - did you mean `IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`?

Comment: Disable constraint and try updating

Comment: You're right: IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX.  I'm not allowed to disable constraint and i don't want to :) I just want to update as many rows as possible and fix the rest manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one with `NOT EXISTS`!

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET EMAILADRESSE = replace(EMAILADRESSE,'@domain1.no','@domain2.no')
 WHERE EMAILADRESSE LIKE '%@domain1.no' 
 AND NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 'X' FROM table1 t2 WHERE t2.EMAILADRESSE = replace(t1.EMAILADRESSE,'@domain1.no','@domain2.no'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it appears looking at the exception message EMAILADRESSE column has a unique contraint. You are trying to update table1 by changing email domain for which at least one of email addresses with replaced domain name already exists.

```
  UPDATE table1
    SET EMAILADRESSE = replace(EMAILADRESSE,'@domain1.no','@domain2.no')
    WHERE EMAILADRESSE LIKE '%@domain1.no' AND   replace(EMAILADRESSE,'@domain1.no','@domain2.no') NOT IN (SELECT EMAILADRESSE FROM table1)
```

Comment: Yes, but i want to just skip thoose and move on to next row. That is what IGNORE_DUP_KEY should do if Oracle supported it.

Comment: I have provided an alternative. But, there could be other ways to do it as well.

Comment: Thanks i'll try the solution :)